# Error casting list of ClassA to ClassB, which is defined as List<ClassA>

Tags: c#-4.0

Question says it all

```
public class SimpleObj : List<Tuple<string, object>>{}
public class ObjCollection : List<SimpleObj>{}
```

Want to cast a List to an ObjCollection and getting the error "Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SimpleObj] to type ObjCollection."

I believe it's working elsewhere so could be a fluke, but it's weird I can't find a way to use implicit operator to force this because it would have to go on a list of SimpleObjs, e.g. an ObjCollection, but it seems you cannot implicitly cast to a class's own type.

Comment: `ObjCollection` and `List<SimpleObj>` are not the same thing.  `ObjCollection` is a class that *inherits* from `List<SimpleObj>` - you can't assign an instance of the base class to a variable of the child class without an explicit cast.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, but an explicit cast would be fine. I just don't seem to be able to use shorthand casting nor write a custom one. What kind of explicit cast are you referring to?

Comment: Either `(ObjCollection)myList` or `myList as ObjCollection` are explicit casts.  Can you post a complete code example that shows how you are casting and produces the build error?